# bootstrap not working in grocery-crud

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using bootstrap to change the theme in `grocery-crud` but my code is not working.

My controller:

```
public function siswa(){
  $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
  $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
  $crud->set_table('murid');
  $output = $crud->render();
  $this->load->view('tampilan',$output);
}
```

Please help me.

error message below

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: include(assets/grocery_crud/themes/bootstrap/config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php
>
> Line Number: 2852
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerycrud\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php
>   Line: 2852 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerycrud\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php
>   Line: 2852 Function: setThemeBasics
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerycrud\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php
>   Line: 4476 Function: setThemeBasics
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerycrud\application\controllers\Coba.php
>   Line: 19 Function: render
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerycrud\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: The error tells you that the theme files does not exist, do you set it up correctly ? Check the directory assets/grocery_crud/themes/bootstrap/config.php
I never tried this theme, I am just  working with datatables &flexigrid.

Comment: I cannot found config.php in bootstrap directory but error message always tell config.php failed to open stream.

I just wanna redesign table using bootstrap.

Comment: try to make a new file named config.php  in that directory, it just have this lines :
<?php 
$config['crud_paging'] = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create config.php file in grocery_crud/themes/bootstrap and put blank

Answer (score 0):

Is easy in the controller add.

```
public function siswa(){
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
    $crud->set_table('murid');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

---

And the view, load all CSS, and bootstrap, etc.

```
<div class="box box-primary">
     <div class="box-body">                    
          <?php echo $output; ?>                          
     </div>
</div>
```